# How is the serial protocol specification for the 3D connexion Magellan / SpaceMouse?

Tags: 3d, serial-port, mouse, protocols

I got hold of an old 3d mouse and would like to use it in an embedded project.
Since 3Dconnexion doesn't support this mouse any more 
I had to reverse engineer myself.
I think I got quite far but could not go on. 
There a side that discibse exactly what I found out:

[http://paulbourke.net/](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/spacemouse/)

I even searched old openSource projects that used the SpaceMouse. 
But non of the implemented more than show on the website above.

Does any body know more about this protocol or webside with information about it it?

Comment: What, specifically are you looking for when you say "more"? Is there some functionality you can't reverse engineer/figure out?

Comment: I can't figure out the meaning of the message headers c , p and e. Their usage for and from the serial host. 
Sometimes they appear but I don't know why they are triggered.